# Calling AWS ELB from CURL - Certificate issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-acm

I'm new to SSL, Certificates etc. I recently created an ACM Certificate and spun up an ELB to use it. I'm able to access the ELB perfectly from the browser.

However when I try to call the SAME ELB from CURL :

```
curl -i -XGET https://REDACTED.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

I get this error. Im not familiar with client side SSL. Do I need to add anything to my client certificate location in order for this to work via CURL?:

```
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160909/how-do-i-deal-with-certificates-using-curl-while-trying-to-access-an-https-url looks like your issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you created the SSL certificate in ACM, you specified the domain name(s). You need to access the ELB using one of those domain names.

The ELB DNS endpoint, which is used for SSL for name lookup, does not match the name in the SSL certificate. This mismatch generates the error that you are seeing.

Solution, go into your DNS server and create an ALIAS or CNAME record mapping your domain name to the ELB DNS endpoint.